# Arcmap [ArcView License only] 10 labels at different scales

Tags: arcmap

Is it possible to have different labels at different scales (without duplicating layers)?

For e.g. I have loads of point shapefiles and would like to label them with ID, Name and postcode.

My idea was to give more information as we zoom in - meaning
1) at full extent - no labels
2) at 1: 1,000,000 - ID only
3) at 1: 500,000 - ID and Name
4) at 1: 100,000 - ID, Name and Postcode

Any ideas or thoughts?

Comment: Do you have the Maplex Extension? With ArcInfo License (standard/advanced) it is available at no extra cost - http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exercise_1_Enabling_the_Maplex_Label_Engine_and_adding_the_Labeling_toolbar/00s800000036000000/

Comment: I just have ArcView License

Comment: Maplex is available by default in ArcMap 10.1. You need to switch it on via the Labeling toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a group layer and put copies of the feature you want to show different labels at different scales in it.  and then you can set a different label expression and a set scale range in the general tab in the layer properties. So when you end up with is a group of the same feature that turns on and off at different scales (make sure to not overlap) and eatch feature has a different label expression.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **label classes**. If you use label classes it is easier to work with **Label Manager** than with Layers Properties Dialog Box. (It also works with ArcView license level and older versions of ArcView.)

1. Open [Labeling toolbar](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_the_Labeling_toolbar/00s800000014000000/)
2. Click on Label Manager Button to open Label Manager
3. add as many label classes as you need (3 in your example)
4. set scale range for each label class

[image]